# How to connect two child themes on different sub domains to the same base theme

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I have my front end site, and a members area located on different sub-domains.

I created my own 'base' theme, and also created a child theme which is now running the front end of the site. Everything is fine here.

I would now like to now create a second child theme, and connect it to the same base theme.

However, the second child theme is on another sub-domain, so I can't simply use approach of:

```
/*
Template: BaseTheme
*/
```

How can I point the second child theme back to the original base theme?

Comment: a bit confusing, are the subdomains part of the same install or not?

Comment: no they are not. Separate wordpress installs. I just want to extend a child theme into a second install.

Comment: I don't see a problem then using the approach you described? As the parent (base) theme is in the same install directory it should be found fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your sites are on the same server and you have SSH access to that server you can set a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) of the master theme folder in the themes folder of your other sites.

I've done it myself with a network of 4 sites that all share the same theme code.

Hope that helps.